# Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

При попытке создать базу данных `new_database` в *adminer* появляется ошибка:

> Access denied for user 'ilnar'@'localhost' to database 'new_database'?

Как быть?)

Comment: Бросай это гиблое дело. Иди в менеджеры.................. А вообще  причина какая? нет пароля или что дальше пишет? А через консоль заходит? Если да - то с паролем? Это ваша база или проектная в компаниии/хосте и т.д.? Нужно больше данных.

Comment: Локальный сервер на Vagrant - е. В adminer-е создал нового юзера. При попытке создать БД ошибка указанная выше. Если пользователь root БД создается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз из под рута все получается, значит надо назначить пользователю `ilnar` права.

Не знаю есть ли такая возможность непосредственно в `adminer`. Наверняка есть. Вам следует поискать эту опцию в программе и назначить нужные права данному пользователю.

Если это делать через БД, то надо будет подключиться рутом и выполнить

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'ilnar'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Звездочки в этой команде задают базу и таблицу, соответственно, к которым у пользователя будет доступ. Если вы хотите дать доступ к любой базе данных или к любой таблице, поставьте звездочку (*) вместо названия базы данных или таблицы.

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES` - чтобы изменения вступили в силу

Для назначения прав конкретному пользователю используется схема:

`GRANT [тип прав] ON [название базы данных].[название таблицы] TO ‘[имя пользователя]’@'localhost’;`

Типы прав:

```
ALL PRIVILEGES - даст пользователю MySQL полный доступ к заданной базе данных (если база данных не указана, то ко всем).
CREATE - позволяет создавать новые таблицы или базы данных.
DROP - позволяет удалять таблицы или базы данных.
DELETE - позволяет удалять строки из таблиц.
INSERT - позволяет добавлять строки в таблицу.
SELECT - поволит использовать команду Select для чтения из баз данных.
UPDATE - позволит редактировать строки таблиц.
GRANT OPTION - позволит назначать или удалять права доступа для других пользователей.
```