# Не могу подключиться к БД (терминал и phpMyAdmin - работают)

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

ОС: Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS)

sudo ufw app list

- Apache
- Apache Full
- Apache Secure
- CUPS

sudo ufw allow in "Apache"

Работает через терминал и phpMyAdmin.
Через PHP - нет.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$host = 'localhost'; //не работает и через '127.0.0.1'
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'пароль';

$sql = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass);
?>
```

Итог:
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in ИСТОЧНИК Stack trace: #0 ИСТОЧНИК: mysqli->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in ИСТОЧНИК

---

Через phpMyAdmin создал пользователя 'userTest' (без пароля) и к нему БД 'userTest' с таблицей 'tabUserTest1' (и добавил одну запись):

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'userTest';
$pass = '';
$db = 'userTest';

$sql = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass); //нет ошибки
```

но для:

```
$sql = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
```

та же ошибка:
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'userTest'@'%' to database 'userTest' ....

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Access denied for user](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473905/access-denied-for-user)